# SQL Server import data

Tags: sql-server, import

When I'm trying to import data from a flat file (text file) to SQL Server, I get some errors:

> Validating (Error)
>   Messages
>   Error 0xc00470b6: Data Flow Task 1: The LocaleID 1 is not installed on this system.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Source - student_TXT" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Help please

Answer (score 1):

When using variable names you can set the setting delay validation to true. That will solve one of your issues. If you could tell us more about what localeid1 is, perhaps we could help you further?